# Create a link to the tag from home age in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am trying to create a navigation bar in the sidebar dynamically. I used the following code:

```
<ul>{% for collection in collections %}
{%if collection.title != 'Frontpage' %}
<li class="abcdef"><span class="heading">{{ collection.title | link_to: collection.url }}</span></li>
<ul>
{% for tag in collection.tags %}  
<li><a href="{{ collection.url }}/{{ tag }}">&emsp;&emsp;{{ tag }}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It was working fine for me but with one exception that my tags must not include spaces. But I have some tags with images. Can you guys, tell me how to do that so, that i can even include space without any interuption?

Comment: The best place to ask this kind of Shopify+Liquid-specific question is in the official Shopify design forums: http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design – you’ll find you’ll get an answer a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using the `link_to_tag` filter.

See: [Link To Tag](http://wiki.shopify.com/Link_to_tag) on the Shopify Wiki.  In your situation, a solution could be:

```
{% for tag in collection.tags %}  
<li><a href="{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}">&emsp;&emsp;{{ tag }}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```